# android sqlite group query error:android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: android-sqlite

My query in android sqlite is given below

MY column name topic,correct_answer and total_mark,test_id
MY database name no_question_list

My query given here

```
           String query = "SELECT topic,SUM(correct_answer),SUM(total_mark)  from no_question_list Where test_id='" + test_id + "'" + "group by topic,correct_answer,total_mark";
           Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query , null);

          if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    topic=  c.getString(0);
                }
                while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

When i execute the query no error when getting error in value of Cursor

```
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stepone.netquestion/com.stepone.netquestion.ResultActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

and i tried this cursor part,it doest execute

```
                  if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                  String topic =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("topic"));                    
                  }
                while (c.moveToNext());
            }
```

thank for answer in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need this test if(c != null) try this code

```
    public String getCol_MPW(){

    db = getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM masterPW";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int i = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_IDI));
        str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Col_MPW));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return str;
    // This routine called from MainActivity determine's if a
    // password has been entered in the db table named "TABLE_PW"
    // See onLoad() method in MainActivity
}
```